# Can src ➜ tsc ➜ rollup ➜ `source maps` point back to the original TypeScript src?

Tags: typescript, source-maps, tsc, rollupjs

I'm using combination of TypeScript and Rollup as is presented in [this article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/06/27/bundling-es2015-modules-with-typescript-and-rollup).

Thus **math.ts**

```
export function square(x: number) {
    return x ** 2;
}

export function cube(x: number) {
    return x ** 3;
}
```

and **main.ts**

```
import { square } from "./math";

console.log(square(3));
```

generates after command

```
tsc -t ES5 -m es2015 && rollup -f es -o app.js -m -i main.js
```

file **app.js**

```
function square(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
}

console.log(square(3));
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

But the generated source map points to the `.js` output of `tsc`, not the original `.ts` files. How can I get the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes. Try [rollup-plugin-sourcemaps](https://github.com/maxdavidson/rollup-plugin-sourcemaps).

Follow the usage at the above link.

Or checkout Alex Jover's [typescript-library-starter](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter) which uses the this plugin as well as others that might solve other problems for you. He also says:

> If you use [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel),
>   you might be able to use the [`inputSourceMap`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#inputsourcemap) option instead of this plugin.

Comment: This is my rollup-plugin-sourcefile result map file - `{"version":3,"file":"index.d.ts","sources":[],"sourcesContent":[],"names":[],"mappings":""}`.   The man page doesn't actually say it can bundle map files - maybe it requires there be only one file being bundled?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems `rollup-plugin-sourcemaps` is no longer being maintained, e.g. it depends on deprecated packages and a [PR](https://github.com/maxdavidson/rollup-plugin-sourcemaps/pull/123) submitted to fix the issue has been sitting idle for several weeks :-(